# Setting up the CLION IDE for c++ on mac computer

Tags: ide, clion

I want to use the CLION IDE and I'am wondering if I need to Download a compiler for my mac computer?

I have read this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/quick-start-guide.html

But to me its not very clear if I need to download one or not. 
Im asking this question since Im not getting Clion working with the libraries I want and I'm trying to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, you *do* need to install a compiler for CLion to be able to run C++ or C programs on it. Macbooks, or iMacs, do not come pre-installed with a compiler.

On a Mac, you can get a compiler by installing XCode. When you install XCode, you also automatically get the necessary Command Line Tools and the latest version of the *Clang* compiler by default, which you can use with Clion to run your code. While the Clang compiler provided by Apple is slightly "*modified*", it will **still** work with any IDE besides XCode.

So what you need to do to get XCode is:

> - Open a Terminal window on your Mac.
> - Type `xcode-select --install` in the terminal and hit "ENTER"
> - A dialog will appear telling you that it requires the Command Line Developer Tools, and will ask if you would like to install them. Click on the "Install" button.

To test the success of the installation of Clang, enter the `clang --version` command into your terminal. If it works, and the version of Clang shows up, then you have successfully installed it on your Mac.

This will get you all the necessary tools on your Mac for you to compile code with your CLion IDE.